# MYSql ORDER BY CASE 1st CASE should order by array of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-order-by, case

I have a Mysql SELECT query that is used in a search function, I want to check an array of ids if they match with the ID in the db.

My client wants it ordered in a specific way so I'll have to use ORDER BY CASE, but I can't seem to figure out how I combine this with the array of ids.  I tried using the FIELD function but this doesn't seem to work in combination with the ORDER BY CASE.

Anybody have any suggestions ?

My ORDER BY so far:

```
   ORDER BY 
            CASE
                WHEN FIELD(p.ID, $implodedArray) THEN '0'
                WHEN p.post_title LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN '1'
                WHEN pm.meta_value LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN '2'
                WHEN p.post_content LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN '3' ELSE '4' END,
```

Comment: Do it in php use in_array to know which ids should have higher priority and take it from there.

Comment: @Mihai depending on the size of the result that could be a huge time sink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**find_in_set()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN FIND_IN_SET(p.ID, $implodedArray) THEN 0
        WHEN p.post_title LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN 1
        WHEN pm.meta_value LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN 2
        WHEN p.post_content LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN 3 
        ELSE 4
    END
```

This is assuming you imploded your array like so

```
implode(',', $some_array);
```

the reason why is because find_in_set uses a comma separated string aka.. `'1,2,3,4,5'`

Comment: I guess find_in_set is blazing fast )

Comment: @Mihai its not too bad since its ordering with a single scan on the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixes my issue :)

Comment: @Lennart sure thing! glad I could help. id appreciate a +1 if you can, I upvoted your question :)

Comment: Gave you a +1 Thanks again !!

Comment: @Lennart dont upvote a ton of my questions at one time. I really appreciate the effort, however SO monitors what they call serial upvoting and will remove them :) just so you know. if you want to upvote a few or think some are good questions / answers upvote them. but dont do too many at a time :)